# How to Add a text box in an URL type menu in Prestashop 1.6 Megamenu?

Tags: html, css, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, megamenu

Hello I need to add some SEO text to one of my Webpage Menu Category.

The problem is that the ''Category'' is not a real category it is and URL Meny Type used for ''offers'' (All the products which includes a discount).
On these page I have no text nor info banner. Just products with discounts.
is there any way I could add at least a box so I can type a well structures SEO text?

Looking forward for you answwer

Answer (score 0):

One way of crudely doing it, (if the page uses the category.tpl file) would be, open the category.tpl file within your theme directory, add a little smarty if statement to check the current category id? or category name, if it matches the desired page, your on.... then show a div with the required SEO text content, obviously not ideal & not dynamic!.. add style code to your css/global.css or css/category.css

to check if the page is using the category files: check the source code body tag!..

ie: **body id="category" class="category category-227"**

```
{if $category->id==YOURCATEGORY || $category->name==YOURCATEGORYNAME}
    <div id="seoContent">
       <p>SEO content!</p>
    </div>
{else}
    <!-- not required page -->
{/if}
```